# How to declare a list as an optional argument in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

First, a little context: I'm learning python (I'm using 2.7.9) and trying to do an exercise where I have to first take a single number which represent the number of my test cases. After that, each test case is a string which contains a series of numbers "2 3 5..." so on. Since it is a pain to convert a single string containing numbers to a list of integers, I created a function named "stringsToInts" to do this for me:

```
def stringsToInts(words, pNumbers = []):
    for word in words:
        pNumbers.append(int(word))
    return pNumbers


print "data:"
testCases = int(raw_input())
numbers = []

while testCases > 0:    
    numbers = stringsToInts(raw_input().split(' ')) 
    testCases -= 1

print "answer:"
for number in numbers:
    print number,
```

However, I noticed something weird. If I define the integer list as an optional argument in my function, this is what happens:

```
(my input in the command line)
data:
2 
2 3 4
6 7 8

(my output)
answer:
2 3 4 6 7 8

(What I expected)
answer:
6 7 8
```

Since I only print `numbers`, why does the list keeps the numbers from all my test cases? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "If a define the integer", I meant "If I define..."

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @vaultah, your link answered my question.

Comment: A web search for mutable default arguments should give you plenty of other info beyond the SO question @vaultah posted.  If you have a choice, you should start your Python journey with 3.x.